# C# additional threads decreases efficiency of application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wanted to stress test my new cpu. I made this in about 2 mins.

**When I add more threads to it, the efficiency of it decreases dramatically.** These are results: (Please note I set the Priority in the taskmanager to High)

1 Thread: *After one minute on 1 thread(s), you got to the number/prime 680263811*

2 Threads: *After one minute on 2 thread(s), you got to the number/prime 360252913*

4 Threads: *After one minute on 4 thread(s), you got to the number/prime 216150449*

There are problems with the code, I just made it as a *test*. Please don't bash me that it was written horribly... I've kinda had a bad day

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Stress test, how many OS threads?: ");
        int thr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Thread[] t = new Thread[thr];
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        UInt64 it = 0;
        UInt64 prime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < thr; i++)
        {

            t[i] = new Thread(delegate() 
            {

                while (s.Elapsed.TotalMinutes < 1)
                {
                    it++;
                    if (it % 2 != 0)// im 100% sure that x % 2 does not give primes, but it uses up the cpu, so idc
                    {
                        prime = it;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("After one minute on " + t.Length + " thread(s), you got to the number/prime " + prime.ToString());//idc if this prints 100 times, this is just a test

            });
            t[i].Start();



        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

**Question: Can someone explain these unexpected results?**

Comment: I'm not an expert in multithreaded applications, but it appears as though these threads aren't interlocked, and multiple threads are incrementing the value while other threads are performing the inspection simultaneously.  This will definitely cause the `it` value to be exponentially larger but the `prime` to be less than expected.  If two threads simultaneously added 1 to the value of `it`, then the next thread that evaluated `it % 2` isn't going to get the opposite of the last result, and won't increment `prime`.

Comment: @Claies That seems most logical. Do you think this is the performance hamper?

Comment: it's not a performance hamper.  It is a false answer from your calculation.  The multiple threads are still doing the work and still performing the calculations, but the only counter you are tracking is one that isn't properly being changed anymore.  If you were to output the value of `it`, it would be 4 times as large with 4 threads, but the value for `prime` would be way off.

Comment: @Claies Right, I expected it to be inaccurate. That explains inaccuracy, but not performance

Comment: that's the thing, the value you are writing out isn't a value that can give you any indication of *performance*.  the value `prime` isn't really telling you anything at all about how hard the threads are working.

Comment: @Nzrpi Are you sure that *performance* is lower? Your lack of thread synchronization means the results you see are wrong, but performance wasn't affected, because the 4-threaded version still did 4 times as much work - it just misreported it.

Comment: @Nzrpi, you aren't checking performance by outputting the final value discovered, because you have errors in how you calculate that value. If you were to output the number of times `it` was incremented, or the number of times a thread assigned a value to `prime`, it would be much higher.

Comment: AvnerShahar-Kashtan Claies moswald Thanks, I can't believe I did not notice that. I'm so dumb :( Can you help me find resources to help me get better and learn more about thread synchronization?

Comment: I think the issue is the way the TickTimer in windows works.  The TickTimer periodically swaps active processes on PC.  There is no guarantee parallel processes will run with equal priority.  Operating System Processes have higher priority and can interrupt your thread randomly.  I would watch taskmanager and change CPU Graph view to logical processes while code is running to see if all the cores are running.  I think the way the code is running you are using only one core.  Creating a thread class will split code among the cores.

Comment: @Nzrpi Thread Synchronization is a broad and complex topic. StackOverflow is a good start. I'd also just search for blogs that talk about it. I don't think I have anything saved, but I'll look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your threads are incrementing `it` without any synchronization, so you're going to get weird results like this. Worse, you're also *assigning* `prime` without any synchronization.

- thread 1: reads `0` from `it`, then gets unscheduled by the OS for whatever reason
- thread 2: reads `0` from `it`, then increments to `1`
- thread 2: does work, assigns `1` to `prime`
- ... thread 2 repeats for awhile. thread 2 is now up to 7, and is about to check `if (it % 2 != 0)`
- thread 1: regains the CPU
- thread 1: increments `it` to `1`
- thread 2: assigns `1` to `prime` --- wat?

The possibilities get even worse as you get to the point where a bit in the high half of `it` is changing because 64-bit reads and writes are not atomic either although these numbers are a little larger than in the question, after running for longer, wildly variable would be possible ... consider

After some time `it = 0x00000000_FFFFFFFF`

- thread 1 reads reads `it` (both words)
- thread 2 reads the higher word `0x0000000_????????`
- thread 1 calculates `it + 1` `0x00000001_00000000`
- thread 1 writes `it` (both halves)
- thread 2 reads the lower word (and puts this with the already read half) `0x00000000_00000000`

While thread 1 was incrementing to 4294967296, thread 2 managed to read 0.

Comment: So this is just a classic case of "too many threads editing the same variable", producing weird results? There was never a performance hamper, only a result flaw?

Comment: Correct. You should use `InterlockedIncrement` instead of `it++`, and a lock around `prime` (although this will drastically reduce your performance, and on such a simple program may actually hurt your runtime).

Comment: @Nzrpi The increment operation is not atomic, reads of 64 bit integers are not atomic and writes of 64 bit integers are not atomic. You're treating them as though they are.

Answer (score -3):

You should apply keyword volatile to variable it and prime.

Comment: modifier "volatile" is not valid for this item

Comment: Beside you need to add more check on prime.

Comment: as long as it takes up cpu, I don't exactly care if it is prime or not.

Comment: If you don't want to move your code, you need to add lock them.